# how to make gps navigation with android

Tags: android, navigation, gps

I want to develop an navigtion turn-by-turn system for my country, El Salvador.
I have a vectorial map for El Salvador very complete, with directions, sites of interest, streets, semaphores, etc.
I'm going to use Android for this and i my question is: what i should to know in order to make this application? Ithing i need to know. 
1. How can I read a vectorial map?
2. How to calculate paths on base of my position?
3. how can i render a vectorial map?

Any help is welcome.
thanks in advance
Julio

Comment: Your first two questions can only be answered by whoever provided you the data file.

Comment: the file is in nm2 format, but i can convert it to other format with gpsmapedit.

Comment: Concerning calculating path you will need heavy math and more precisely the Graph Theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory you first need to understand that before doing anything

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to render vectorial tiles and data, we are about to provide a freshly baked javascript API and a mobile native API for map tools.
Checkout the features, you could find what you need : http://www.maperial.com/#/features